# The client must not make any assumptions regarding the internal implementation

Tags: ejb-3.1, java-ee-7, ejb-3.2

the full sentence taken from the EJB3.2 specifications:

> When interacting with a reference to the no-interface view, the client
>   must not make any assumptions regarding the internal implementation of
>   the  reference, such as any instance-specific state that may be
>   present in the reference

I'm actually trying to understand what that actually mean and I was wondering if someone could kindly provide some examples.

**EDIT**:
The Above sentence is take from Section 3.4.4 Session Bean’s No-Interface View, maybe this info is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating a no-interface view proxy, the EJB container must create a subclass of the EJB class and override all public methods to provide proxying behavior (like security, transactions).

You can get a reference to the bean with (eg. for passing it to another ejb):

```
NoInterfaceBean bean = ejbContext.getBusinessObject(NoInterfaceBean.class);
```

This returns a reference with a **class-type that is the same as the bean class itself** (normally if the EJB has a business interface it would return the interface class), but **it is not a reference to an instance of NoInterfaceBean** (but to that proxy class with the same name). Think of it as a **reference to a pimped version** of your bean, about which you

> *must not make any assumptions regarding the internal implementation*

It's basically the same with "normal" EJB's. You know that there is some magic around your bean instance, but since you get the interface as class-type it's already clear that every class implementing the interface can have a different internal implementation.

So the specification emphasizes this difference at that point. Even if it looks like a reference to your concrete class it is none (as they say in the next paragraph of the specification [JSR-000345 Enterprise JavaBeansTM 3.2 Final Release](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-spec/ejb-3_2-core-fr-spec.pdf):

> Although the reference object is type-compatible with the
>   corresponding bean  class type, there is no prescribed relationship
>   between the internal implementation of the reference and the
>   implementation of the bean instance.